# Excel Array formula #N/A error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using an excel array function to select a range and apply formula based on reference cells. But, everytime i add or remove a values, i am able to copy paste the references using macro but the array formula is not updating the range to reselect the new range.

Here is my main table on top and bottom table what i want sing an array formula which i already achieved but when updating using vba its not taking new entries added/deleted by updating the range in the formula.

```
No. Name    V1  V3  V3  V4
1   Wood    10  10  10  10
2   wood    28  28  28  28
3   tree    30  45  60  68
4   plastic 50  50  50  50
5   tree    50  50  50  50
6   iron    64  75  75  80


No. Name        V1  V3  V3  V4
1   Wood - A    25  25  25  25
2   Wood - A    50  50  50  50
3   tree - A    50  50  75  75
4   plastic - A 75  75  75  75
5   tree - A    75  75  75  75
6   iron - A    75  100 100 100
```

First formula: Name column

```
=concatenate(A1:A6," - A")
```

- Ctrl+shift+enter - is giving me what i need in right table names column.

Second formula: values change

```
=value(if(C1:F6<25,"25",if(C1:F6<50,"50",if(C1:F6<75,"75","100"))))
```

This formula i used to assign actual values and the values in left table is forecast values. I can achieve this even using array "ctrl+shift+enter".

Problem:
But the problem, is everytime i update a sheet by adding new entries like A7,A8,A9 while applying the formula using vba it's not taking the new range as A1:A9(A1:A6) for first formula and C1:F9(C1:C6) for second formula but taking the old ranges in brackets. Because, of which i am getting errors like #N/A as its not taking new range, so formula couldn't understand what is in the remaining cells.

Comment: It would help if you provided your code. you might want to look up setting range to last row.

Comment: I'm unclear on why the column header labels are v1, **v3**, v3, v4.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

[image]

Put this in the worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:F")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range, tr As Long, v As Long
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:F"))
            tr = t.Row
            If Cells(tr, "B").Value2 <> vbNullString And _
              Application.Count(Range(Cells(tr, "A"), Cells(tr, "F"))) = 5 Then
                Cells(tr, "A").Offset(0, 7) = Cells(tr, "A").Value
                Cells(tr, "B").Offset(0, 7) = Cells(tr, "B").Value & " - A"
                For v = 3 To 6
                    Select Case Cells(tr, v).Value
                        Case Is < 25
                            Cells(tr, v).Offset(0, 7) = 25
                        Case Is < 50
                            Cells(tr, v).Offset(0, 7) = 50
                        Case Is < 75
                            Cells(tr, v).Offset(0, 7) = 75
                        Case Else
                            Cells(tr, v).Offset(0, 7) = 100
                    End Select
                Next v
            End If
        Next t
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Result after adding two rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update! but i am still facing issues. I have attached my vba code and detail description in below question, i would appeciate, if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199634/array-issue-n-a